# Tokens on Child Items

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

I am using Sitecore in a Headless mode using the JSS.  I have never tried to make any changes to the CM/functionality behind the CM, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am current researching for a way to use tokens of a parent page in a child item.  Currently it sounds like it is not possible.

Example:  I have a page called My Sample Page and there is a datasource in the Page Content called Page Data (My Sample Page -> Page Content -> Page Data).

Is there a way to use $name to set a field in Page Data to be "My Sample Page"?  Is there a different way to resolve this?

Comment: https://soen.ghost.io/working-with-custom-tokens-in-sitecore/   might help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom token to achieve it. Create a custom Token processor inheriting `ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor` with the following code. It checks if the value of the field contains the `$ancestortitle` token. If it does it checks if the parent is not null. If the parent is not null and there are parent of parent item the value is set to the field.

```
using Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue;
 
    public class TokenAncestorTitleProcessor : ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(ExpandInitialFieldValueArgs args)
        {
            if (args.SourceField.Value.Contains("$ancestortitle"))
            {
                if (args.TargetItem != null && args.TargetItem.Parent != null && args.TargetItem.Parent.Parent != null)
                {
                    //Replace any specific filed value like here used Title from parent item
                    args.Result = args.Result.Replace("$ancestortitle", args.TargetItem.Parent.Parent.Fields["Title"].Value);
                    
                    // If you want to replace Name of the parent then uncomment below line and comment above one.
                    //args.Result = args.Result.Replace("$ancestortitle", args.TargetItem.Parent.Parent.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Config change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <expandInitialFieldValue>
          <processor resolve="true" type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.TokenAncestorTitleProcessor, MyAssembly" patch:after="processor[@type='type=Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ReplaceVariables, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
        </expandInitialFieldValue>  
      </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Template configuration:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/standard-values.html

These are default tokens available. If they doesn't serve the purpose, create custom token.

https://sitecorecorner.com/2014/08/03/sitecore-custom-tokens/comment-page-1/